Hibernate HQL fails due to wrong column chosen by hibernate
The code below worked fine with Hibernate 5.6.x but now fails after upgrading to hibernate 6.5.2.Final.
@MappedSuperclass()
public class ModelCore {
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue()
    private Long dbID;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { 
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "ID" }) 
        }, 
        name = Certificate.TABLE_NAME)
public class Certificate extends ModelCore {

    @Basic()
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String iD;
...
}

Query code that triggers failure:
Query<Certificate> query = session.createQuery("FROM Certificate WHERE ID=:param", Certificate.class)
query.setParameter("param", "beed827cd6814a75961329dd477a2194"); 

Resulting exception:
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [beed827cd6814a75961329dd477a2194] did not match expected type [SqmBasicValuedSimplePath(cmb.domain.model.Certificate(2283051504511200).dbID)]
  #0: org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:124)
  #1: org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractCommonQueryContract.setParameter(AbstractCommonQueryContract.java:842)
  #2: org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.setParameter(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:882)
  #3: org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.setParameter(QuerySqmImpl.java:1200)
  #4: org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.setParameter(QuerySqmImpl.java:136)
  #5: org.mangogrove.infrastructure.persistence.hibernate.AbstractHibernateRepository.findValuesByKey(AbstractHibernateRepository.java:259)

For some reason the column value choosen by hibernate is "dbID" (Long) when it should be using "ID" (String).  I don't understand what has changed so much that this is now broken.
